# Using powershell, get the pagelayout name for a given aspx page in the Pages Library

Tags: document-library, powershell, page-layout, pages

I am writing a powershell script to list out all the pages in a given Pages library. But I would like to get only those pages with a given pagelayout. Is it possible to get this information from the Page library item?

The way I am currently getting the in items is using the SPFolder.Files way. Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty; this seems to work:

```
Function GetFilesWithSpecificPageLayout($Folder, $PageLayoutName)
{ 
    foreach($file in $Folder.Files)
    {   
        $usesGivenPageLayout = $false
        foreach ($blink in $file.BackwardLinks)
        {
            if($blink.Url.ToLower() -match $PageLayoutName.ToLower())
            {
                $usesGivenPageLayout = $true
                break
            }
        }
        if(-not $usesGivenPageLayout)
        {
            foreach ($flink in $file.ForwardLinks)
            {
                if($flink.Url.ToLower() -match $PageLayoutName.ToLower())
                {
                    $usesGivenPageLayout = $true
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        if($usesGivenPageLayout)
        {
            Write-Host "`t" $file.Name
        }
    }

    #Loop through all subfolders and call the function recursively
    foreach ($SubFolder in $Folder.SubFolders)
    {
        if($SubFolder.Name -ne "Forms")
        {  
            if($PageLayoutName -ne "")
            {
                Write-Host "`t" -NoNewline
            }
            GetFilesWithSpecificPageLayout($Subfolder)($PageLayoutName)
        }
    }
 }

#Get the Site collection 
$Site= Get-SPSite "http://sitecollection.url" 

#Loop throuh all Sub Sites
foreach($Web in $Site.AllWebs)
{
    Write-Host "'$($web.Title)' at $($web.URL)"
    foreach($list in $Web.Lists)
    {
        #Filter Doc Libs, Eliminate Hidden ones
        if(($List.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") -and ($List.Hidden -eq $false) -and ($List.Title -eq "Pages"))
        { 
            GetFilesWithSpecificPageLayout($List.RootFolder)("PageLayoutNameHere")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess this will do the trick.. But I haven't tested it.

```
$site = get-SPSite http://mysite.com
$web = $site.RootWeb
$pweb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)

$pPages = $pWeb.GetPublishingPages();
$pLayouts = $pweb.GetAvailablePageLayouts()
foreach ($pPage in $pPages)
{
    if ($pPage.Layout -eq $pLayouts)
    {
        write-host $pPage.Title
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But this did not work out as expected. It looks like my site collection only has 2 publishing webs; there are a ton of other sites where I am looking to get the pages from. Also, we are comparing a collection with a string in the last if statement here. I will play around with this. But if you could think of anything else, please let me know. Thank you again!

Comment: oh sorry.. guess you need to find the correct layout in the layouts  collection.. something like 
foreach($pLayout in $pLayouts) 
{
if ($pLayout.Title -eq "Mylayout") { $findLayout == $playout }
}

and then compare with that instead

Comment: Worked for me, cheers!